# Multiple tags in Music

Tags: itunes, music, music.app, metadata, id3-tag

I separate tags using the semicolon, but macOS' inbuilt Music app doesn't appear to recognize them as separate tags.
As a result, I see entries, such as "Cover; Dance" and "CoverJazz" (unsure why the semicolon is omitted in the latter), containing only the tracks tagged as such. At the same time, these tracks are not shown under "Cover," "Dance" or "Jazz."

Other metadata fields, such as Artists, suffer from the same issue.

[image: Multiple genre and artist tags per track in column browser]

How can I make Music behave like Foobar2000 or MusicBee which treat tags as tags?
In those programs, tags have a many-to-many relationship with tracks.
For example, a track can belong to many genres, and a genre can have many tracks belong to it.

Comment: There are many columns available in macOS Music which IMHO can be used for more detailed taxonomy like Category, Kind, Grouping, Description, Comments